# Create x509 certificate with openssl/makecert tool

Tags: security, encryption, openssl, rsa, makecert

I'm creating a x509 certificate using makecert with the following parameters:

> makecert -r -pe -n "CN=Client" -ss MyApp

I want to use this certificate to encrypt and decrypt data with RSA algoritm.
I look to generated certificate in windows certificate store and everything seems ok (It has a private key, public key is a RSA key with 1024 bits and so on..)

Now i use this C# code to encrypt data:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("MyApp", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "Client", false);
X509Certificate2 _x509 = certs[0];

using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)_x509.PublicKey.Key)
{
    byte[] dataToEncrypt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello");
    _encryptedData = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, true);
}
```

When executing the Encrypt method, i receive a CryptographicException with message "Bad key".

I think the code is fine. Probably i'm not creating the certificate properly.
Any comments?
Thanks

---------------- EDIT --------------
If anyone know how to create the certificate using OpenSsl, its also a valid answer for me.

Comment: When creating your cert what is the bit of the private/public key pairs you specify ?

probably you have to specify longer keys 4048 bits?

Comment: I not sure what option are you talking about. I just used the options i show above in makecert command. If you are talking about one other, assume the default value. But my public key has 1024 bits.

Comment: okey then i never use makecert just search to create it 4048 bits.1024 bits is broken for that reason you can get the error.

Comment: Thanks Berkay.I tried the option -len 2048 and -len 4096. But the problem continues.

Comment: This: http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/doc/manual/privatekeyaccessproblems.html site has a nice set of steps for creating and exporting certificates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow the key to be used for encryption, you should use the [`-sky`-option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386968(VS.85).aspx). Per default ´makecert` uses the AT_SIGNATURE key specification, which will not work with encryption/decryption. Instead have it use the AT_KEYEXCHANGE specification by issuing the following command:

```
makecert -r -pe -n "CN=Client" -ss MyApp -sky Exchange
```

(Remember to delete the previous key or use another container-name).

Comment: I read RSA algoritm could be used both to sign and encrypt messages. It is impossible to have in just one cert the cipher and sign keys?

Comment: An AT_KEYEXCHANGE can be used for both signing and encryption, just not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

This was another page I stumbled across when I was trying to find examples of makcert usage with x509 certificates and rsa using c#, and unfortunately it only provided part of the solution. I put all the bits together in a blog entry that people might be interested in, and it can be found here:
http://nick-howard.blogspot.com/2011/05/makecert-x509-certificates-and-rsa.html